# How to setup global npm module to be executed over cron in mac os x

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, cron

I have installed a global npm module say it be, 'global-npm-runner'

i have installed `global-npm-runner` globally with `-g`

It also needs some arguments to run. So to run on new terminal i simply do

`global-npm-runner -E=<my_email> -U="<some_url>"`

and it works smoothly

info :

`whereis global-npm-runner` gives blank

`type global-npm-runner` gives `/usr/local/bin/global-npm-runner`

to run the above every 2 minutes i add it to cron like this

`*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/global-npm-runner -E=<my_email> -U="<some_url>"`

but it does

following error when i look into the /var/mail/me

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Any solution to this problem

Comment: What's the very first line of `/usr/local/bin/global-npm-runner`?

Comment: its `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Comment: That looks okay. There's, roughly speaking, two things that can go wrong: that line (which is okay), and the command entry in the crontab. For instance, some characters have a special meaning in a crontab (like `%`), so should be escaped. Also, not sure if you're actually doing it, but try putting quotes around the e-mail address as well.

Comment: I even removed all the parameters and simply putting this line `*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/global-npm-runner` for removing special character doubts..  But it gives `env: node: No such file or directory` .. can you please experiment with simplest global npm module in cron and if you got success, please post that as answer

Comment: Can you run `which node` in your shell?

Comment: it says `/usr/local/bin/node`, let me try adding this as first line.. thanx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137209/discussion-between-codeofnode-and-robertklep).